# how to autocomplete values based on a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I created many Lists and they are getting longer. At the moment i am using data validation, so I have big lists and need to select the name i want

They are all listed on my formulas, so i would like to know if there is any way 
to start to write the name that i need and excel already shows the
possibilities...

I tried to use this formula but was not successful

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,MATCH("*",Sheet1!$A$1:$A$300,-1),1)
```

For instance i have a list of currencies called "CCY", i would like to write 
"US" and excel already shows USD. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: There is one way I know of using autocomplete without VBA. It is placing the sample of data right above your table. When you start writing the content it gets autocompleted. The formulae can find your value too but will not write it without human interception.

Answer (score 0):

```
=OFFSET(Currency,MATCH(A2&"*",Currency,0)-1,0) 'A2 is where the validation applies, make sure it accepts values not in list
```

You can enter the value in a second go, will let you select from values after.
I wouldn't use it but

1. It will let you select any value from the drop-down
2. You can let it do its job by typing "*us*", *Tab*, *Shift+Tab*, *Alt+Down* and *Tab* quite fast.

The formula below won't let you select values after, takes the first match only, handle with care.

```
=OFFSET(Currency,MATCH(A2&"*",Currency,0)-1,0,1,1) 'fun fact: you can give names to data table columns thus creating expanding lists
```

Comment: If you are content with my answer feel free to accept it. For VBA-enhanced listing (that would actually fill the gap) submit/resubmit your question with the VBA tag.